# How to compute Total Harmonic Distortion (THD) for the following signal?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

The signal is as follows

```
Sin[x - j]
```

with $j$ being

```
j = -2 ArcTan[(0.25021321044272604` Cos[2 x] + 
       2 \[Sqrt](1.1070153486505345` - 
           0.23821744233962883` Cos[2 x] - 
           0.31269725058653813` Sin[2 x]) - 
       0.19061616601824882` Sin[2 x])/(-3.8844055586210424` + 
       0.19061616601824882` Cos[2 x] + 
       0.25021321044272604` Sin[2 x])];
```

The computation of total harmonic distortion requires the calculation of Fourier Series which I am not able to achieve.
$THD=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}V_{_{n-rms}}^{{2}}}{V_{fundametal-rms}}}$

More details can be found [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-importance-of-total-harmonic-distortion/).
I tried using the built in `FourierSeries` function but it doesn't return anything. Any help would be highly appreciated.